# OEL6 Slow boot && Millions of socket files in /tmp/orbit-gdm

Tags: xorg, socket, gdm, tmp, oracle-linux

**Background on question**

Lately I've been having some trouble with slow booting on the servers, sometimes over 2 hours to boot stuck on "Enabling Local Filesystem Quotas:"

After searching I managed to narrow it down to /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit specifically:

```
# Clean up various /tmp bits
[ -n "$SELINUX_STATE" ] && restorecon /tmp
rm -f /tmp/.X*-lock /tmp/.lock.* /tmp/.gdm_socket /tmp/.s.PGSQL.*
rm -rf /tmp/.X*-unix /tmp/.ICE-unix /tmp/.font-unix /tmp/hsperfdata_* \
   /tmp/kde-* /tmp/ksocket-* /tmp/mc-* /tmp/mcop-* /tmp/orbit-*  \
   /tmp/scrollkeeper-*  /tmp/ssh-* \
   /dev/.in_sysinit
```

The exact cause of the slow booting is `rm -rf /tmp/orbit-*` due to a truly massive amount of socket files being generated and not removed except on boot.

The files are owned by user & group GDM and are named linc-rand-0-longrandom
ex: linc-1e33-0-54b542d8de62e

The file count has grown to 1 million on at lease one occasion.
The size of the folder has been recorded to be up to 3.1GB in size as well.

note: the socket files themselves are empty however each file reserves the minimum amount of disk space depending of filesystem type and setup.
(usually 2048 or 4096)

While I have a temporary solution (See below) I would very much like to track down the cause.
And so this brings me to

**The question:**

## How do I track down the event that is causing GDM to generate these files?

**Notes and system info:**

- OS: Oracle Linux 6.7 (current)
- Kernel Linux 3.8.13-118.2.2.el6uek.x86_64
- GNOME v2.28.2
- <s>We connect using Teamviewer 9, This is our only suspect at this time.</s>
- [Possibly the same issue on opensuse 11.4](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698243#c2)
- [What looks to be the same issue again on RHEL 6.6](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258459)
- [Another person who encountered this. (in comments)](http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html)
- Quick fix for anyone googling this: boot into a live cd with the linux of your choice, mount the root drive and simply mv /tmp/orbit-gdm /tmp/(Anything not caught by /tmp/orbit-*) then rm it after the system boots with your choice of tools (rm -rf, perl, rsync ect.)

**Update 1**
We might have found a slightly better temporary solution.
`su gdm -c linc-cleanup-sockets`
To run this you need the ORBit2-devel package and user gdm needs a bash shell.

One-Liner:
`sudo yum install ORBit2-devel -y && sudo chsh /bin/bash gdm && sudo su gdm -c linc-cleanup-sockets`

Then add the last part to a cronjob. (Warning! While there are no apparent issues on my system chsh may still break something)

**Update 2**

Finally caught it in the act, It's generating about 15-20 files a second right now.

per DopeFish's suggestion:
`lsof | grep /tmp/orbit-gdm` returns:

> gnome-ses 13197       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff8802f3460c40        0t0      45587 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-338d-0-5188b15791c84
>   gnome-ses 13197       gdm   18u     unix 0xffff8802f3460540        0t0      45589 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-338d-0-5188b15791c84
>   gnome-ses 13197       gdm   23u     unix 0xffff8801dbacb480        0t0      45023 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-338d-0-5188b15791c84
>   gnome-ses 13860       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff88022b7ca3c0        0t0      45450 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3624-0-66bb9358d7045
>   gnome-ses 13860       gdm   18u     unix 0xffff8802ee3f84c0        0t0      45452 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3624-0-66bb9358d7045
>   gnome-ses 13860       gdm   21u     unix 0xffff880236d9c840        0t0      45571 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3624-0-66bb9358d7045
>   gnome-ses 13860       gdm   24u     unix 0xffff8801f0177b80        0t0      45024 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3624-0-66bb9358d7045
>   gconfd-2  13929       gdm   11u     unix 0xffff8802f0eec180        0t0      45441 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3669-0-14722d39cdaf5
>   gconfd-2  13929       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff8801fffef540        0t0      45449 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3669-0-14722d39cdaf5
>   gconfd-2  13929       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff88021e34f8c0        0t0      41772 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3669-0-14722d39cdaf5
>   gconfd-2  13929       gdm   19u     unix 0xffff8801d30d4740        0t0      50348 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3669-0-14722d39cdaf5
>   at-spi-re 13953       gdm   11u     unix 0xffff8801e171e480        0t0      47205 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3681-0-14f52f55664c
>   at-spi-re 13953       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8801db8903c0        0t0      47206 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3681-0-14f52f55664c
>   gnome-set 13957       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff88021e34f540        0t0      41773 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3685-0-75f6d21d31afb
>   gnome-set 13957       gdm   16u     unix 0xffff8801db890ac0        0t0      41775 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3685-0-75f6d21d31afb
>   gnome-set 13957       gdm   21u     unix 0xffff880236d9c140        0t0      45018 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3685-0-75f6d21d31afb
>   gnome-set 13957       gdm   24u     unix 0xffff8802ef6f7800        0t0      41867 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3685-0-75f6d21d31afb
>   bonobo-ac 13959       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8802266e7400        0t0      44959 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3687-0-3a8011046106
>   bonobo-ac 13959       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff880226763800        0t0      45517 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3687-0-3a8011046106
>   gconfd-2  13976       gdm   11u     unix 0xffff8801dbb097c0        0t0      45561 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3698-0-2c02c3e28e028
>   gconfd-2  13976       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff8801db93f180        0t0      45586 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3698-0-2c02c3e28e028
>   gconfd-2  13976       gdm   19u     unix 0xffff8801d86997c0        0t0      45737 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3698-0-2c02c3e28e028
>   gconfd-2  13976       gdm   22u     unix 0xffff8801d60e7b00        0t0      41871 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3698-0-2c02c3e28e028
>   gconfd-2  13976       gdm   24u     unix 0xffff8801d306f3c0        0t0      50355 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3698-0-2c02c3e28e028
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   11u     unix 0xffff8802e0222880        0t0      49490 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8801d8619b80        0t0      45740 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   14u     unix 0xffff8802f0f29c40        0t0      49566 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   16u     unix 0xffff8802edc7e440        0t0      41858 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   18u     unix 0xffff8801d60b9400        0t0      41860 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   20u     unix 0xffff8801d60dc440        0t0      41865 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   22u     unix 0xffff8801d6171c00        0t0      48731 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   24u     unix 0xffff880170bd5c40        0t0  199299807 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   30u     unix 0xffff8801d6369b00        0t0      41886 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   32u     unix 0xffff8801d63aa4c0        0t0      41889 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   34u     unix 0xffff8801d4555800        0t0      50338 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   at-spi-re 13978       gdm   36u     unix 0xffff8801dbbab8c0        0t0      47488 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-369a-0-1882b699bb820
>   bonobo-ac 13986       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff8801fcd3cac0        0t0      49488 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36a2-0-362b8becbb48a
>   bonobo-ac 13986       gdm   16u     unix 0xffff8801fcc21180        0t0      49492 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36a2-0-362b8becbb48a
>   gnome-set 13988       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff8801d8699440        0t0      48707 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36a4-0-32757e4fb7e52
>   gnome-set 13988       gdm   16u     unix 0xffff8801dbb67400        0t0      48708 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36a4-0-32757e4fb7e52
>   gnome-set 13988       gdm   20u     unix 0xffff88022b7caac0        0t0      49575 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36a4-0-32757e4fb7e52
>   metacity  13998       gdm   14u     unix 0xffff8801d6171880        0t0      48732 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36ae-0-23e4b5d7b7629
>   metacity  13998       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff8801d6171180        0t0      41872 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36ae-0-23e4b5d7b7629
>   metacity  13998       gdm   18u     unix 0xffff8801d60e7400        0t0      41874 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36ae-0-23e4b5d7b7629
>   plymouth- 14009       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8801d63aa140        0t0      48800 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36b9-0-705176425477
>   plymouth- 14009       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff8801d63a87c0        0t0      51377 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36b9-0-705176425477
>   plymouth- 14011       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8801d6369780        0t0      41887 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36bb-0-77c5f78814cf
>   plymouth- 14011       gdm   15u     unix 0xffff8801d6369080        0t0      47583 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36bb-0-77c5f78814cf
>   gnome-pow 14016       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8801d45561c0        0t0      47489 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36c0-0-4cbeb08e2eb07
>   gnome-pow 14016       gdm   16u     unix 0xffff8801d61a4ac0        0t0      50356 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36c0-0-4cbeb08e2eb07
>   gnome-pow 14016       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff8801d84f2b00        0t0      50358 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36c0-0-4cbeb08e2eb07
>   gnome-pow 14018       gdm   12u     unix 0xffff8801d30b3440        0t0      50339 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36c2-0-20a8f4a82d8c3
>   gnome-pow 14018       gdm   16u     unix 0xffff8801d30b30c0        0t0      50349 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36c2-0-20a8f4a82d8c3
>   gnome-pow 14018       gdm   17u     unix 0xffff8801d306fac0        0t0      50351 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-36c2-0-20a8f4a82d8c3
>   metacity  59825       gdm   14u     unix 0xffff88012af42400        0t0  199299808 /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-e9b1-0-34f9216742ceb

`su gdm -c linc-cleanup-sockets`

> Cleaned 41672 files 16 still live

**Update 3**
Disabling teamviewer when the file generation was occurring slowed it by about %30 but did not stop it.

This was tested by enabling TV and Disabling it multiple times on two servers.
So while TV makes the issue worse it does not appear to be the root cause.

(another resource for anyone who comes across this with the same problem)
`#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  su gdm -c linc-cleanup-sockets
  sleep 10
done`

**Update 4**
I came across three files in /var/log of unusual size.
/var/log/gdm/:0-greeter.log.1 (1.2G)
/var/log/gdm/:0.log.4 (2.7G)
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old (3.1G)

All three continue like this for thousands of lines.

:0-greeter.log.1

> Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
>   Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
>   Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
>   Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.

:0.log.4

> AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49017 )
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49017 )
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49018 )
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49018 )
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49019 )
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49019 )
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 18 disconnected
>   AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:28 2016: 11177: client 12 disconnected

Xorg.0.log.old

> [604786.284] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 12 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49530 )
>   [604786.300] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 18 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49530 )
>   [604786.325] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 18 disconnected
>   [604786.326] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 12 disconnected
>   [604786.366] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 12 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49541 )
>   [604786.390] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 18 connected from local host ( uid=42 gid=42 pid=49541 )
>   [604786.414] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 18 disconnected
>   [604786.416] AUDIT: Sat Jan 16 03:00:37 2016: 11177: client 12 disconnected

Hopefully these are of use to someone who can help resolve this.

**Update 5**
More info

`netstat -avep | grep gdm`

> unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33469  14221/gconfd-2      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-378d-0-739b151848686
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     49272  14203/gnome-session /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-377b-0-446c29ed00d3
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     49290  14252/gnome-setting /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ac-0-4c1973905a173
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     49298  14284/bonobo-activa /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37cc-0-7163b16fe1d1
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     49300  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34703  14293/metacity      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37d5-0-399c705510867
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43204  14295/plymouth-log- /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37d7-0-76c2752e521e6
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     45461  14303/polkit-gnome- /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37df-0-7e28a833c25b4
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     45476  14302/gnome-power-m /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37de-0-13af029d53568
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44354  14298/gdm-simple-gr /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37da-0-677e125a55c9f
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49319  14293/metacity      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37d5-0-399c705510867
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49972  14302/gnome-power-m /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37de-0-13af029d53568
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49317  14293/metacity      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37d5-0-399c705510867
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49312  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     43203  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49301  14284/bonobo-activa /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37cc-0-7163b16fe1d1
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     40228  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49968  14295/plymouth-log- /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37d7-0-76c2752e521e6
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49274  14203/gnome-session /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-377b-0-446c29ed00d3
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     45460  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49271  14221/gconfd-2      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-378d-0-739b151848686
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49982  14298/gdm-simple-gr /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37da-0-677e125a55c9f
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     45475  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49980  14298/gdm-simple-gr /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37da-0-677e125a55c9f
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33588  14203/gnome-session /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-377b-0-446c29ed00d3
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     44353  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49314  14252/gnome-setting /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ac-0-4c1973905a173
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49309  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49979  14221/gconfd-2      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-378d-0-739b151848686
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49292  14252/gnome-setting /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ac-0-4c1973905a173
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49289  14221/gconfd-2      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-378d-0-739b151848686
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49971  14221/gconfd-2      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-378d-0-739b151848686
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49974  14302/gnome-power-m /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37de-0-13af029d53568
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49316  14221/gconfd-2      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-378d-0-739b151848686
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34702  14243/at-spi-regist /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a3-0-102d46a4e4c2
>   unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     45487  14303/polkit-gnome- /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37df-0-7e28a833c25b4

**Update 6**
Another data dump.
`ss -xprms | grep /tmp/orbit-gdm`

> u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a5-0-54e93c0d4f464 35701                 * 0     users:(("gconfd-2",14245,17))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b7-0-3777a325db022 35704                 * 0     users:(("gnome-settings-",14263,16))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 35714                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,12))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 43672                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,16))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b7-0-3777a325db022 43674                 * 0     users:(("gnome-settings-",14263,22))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 43715                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,22))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3788-0-6dfd943157cc8 43931                 * 0     users:(("gnome-session",14216,20))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ef-0-1e25b2118b9a 45957                 * 0     users:(("plymouth-log-vi",14319,15))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37f2-0-48c1a4853a3c7 46524                 * 0     users:(("polkit-gnome-au",14322,14))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 47375                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,18))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a5-0-54e93c0d4f464 47381                 * 0     users:(("gconfd-2",14245,19))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ed-0-48c0a255e98d7 47382                 * 0     users:(("metacity",14317,17))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ed-0-48c0a255e98d7 47384                 * 0     users:(("metacity",14317,18))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a5-0-54e93c0d4f464 47449                 * 0     users:(("gconfd-2",14245,21))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37f1-0-62b916ee3bde0 47450                 * 0     users:(("gnome-power-man",14321,16))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37f1-0-62b916ee3bde0 47452                 * 0     users:(("gnome-power-man",14321,17))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 47736                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,20))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e7-0-7cd34eb474672 47748                 * 0     users:(("bonobo-activati",14567,3))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38f1-0-78fed63f87292 47760                 * 0     users:(("gnome-power-man",14577,16))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b9-0-bf39f0ecfb18 48325                 * 0     users:(("bonobo-activati",14265,16))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 48379                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,26))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37a5-0-54e93c0d4f464 50179                 * 0     users:(("gconfd-2",14245,15))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-376e-0-117b4e816d611 50182                 * 0     users:(("gnome-session",14190,18))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 50208                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,14))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-376e-0-117b4e816d611 50210                 * 0     users:(("gnome-session",14190,23))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 50224                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,24))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e1-0-31fe4fb874870 51339                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14561,15))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38ef-0-3a6bdd32842f6 51345                 * 0     users:(("plymouth-log-vi",14575,15))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e1-0-31fe4fb874870 52271                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14561,14))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e1-0-31fe4fb874870 52272                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14561,16))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e1-0-31fe4fb874870 53454                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14561,12))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38f2-0-9677e70872af 53504                 * 0     users:(("polkit-gnome-au",14578,14))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b3-0-5db00428cfe2a 54300                 * 0     users:(("at-spi-registry",14259,32))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e5-0-700f791271f64 54308                 * 0     users:(("gnome-settings-",14565,18))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-3788-0-6dfd943157cc8 92320134                 * 0     users:(("gnome-session",14216,19))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37f1-0-62b916ee3bde0 92320192                 * 0     users:(("gnome-power-man",14321,19))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-376e-0-117b4e816d611 92320212                 * 0     users:(("gnome-session",14190,25))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e5-0-700f791271f64 92320226                 * 0     users:(("gnome-settings-",14565,4))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37b7-0-3777a325db022 92320416                 * 0     users:(("gnome-settings-",14263,23))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38f1-0-78fed63f87292 92320540                 * 0     users:(("gnome-power-man",14577,15))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-37ed-0-48c0a255e98d7 92320754                 * 0     users:(("metacity",14317,20))
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-38e1-0-31fe4fb874870 102557171                 * 0
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-861e-0-600072181468c 102557177                 * 0
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-86bb-0-50ee4ccb72362 102557178                 * 0
>   u_str  ESTAB      0      0      /tmp/orbit-gdm/linc-86bb-0-50ee4ccb72362 102557180                 * 0

**Update 6**

Finally some progress, We have determined that this is directly linked to $DISPLAY

Some of the time $DISPLAY is set to :1.0 rather than the default :0.0

If anyone knows why this causes GNOME to generate a massive amount of socket files  OR Why it is :1.0 some of the time either will do as an answer.

I will be opening another separate question for DISPLAY and will link it to this one.

---

This question is getting rather long if anyone has any suggestions on what I can do to streamline and remove the useless info from it please comment or suggest an edit.

Also if there is a particular reason I'm not getting any responses or upvotes please let me know in a comment so I can improve this question.

Comment: You could try running `lsof` and `grep`ping the output for programs that have file handles open to those "temporary" files.  You will then know who the culprit is.  You should, if you have the RAM, look into making `/tmp` a `tmpfs` (RAM disk) filesystem, which by its nature, will be purges at reboot or shutdown.

Comment: sudo lsof | grep /tmp/orbit- returns /tmp/orbit-root and /tmp/orbit-oracle but no /tmp/orbit-gdm

Comment: That means you have something on your system that is dropping "temporary" files but not cleaning up after itself.  `lsof` shows active file handles at the instant the program is running; you will have to repeatedly try it until you catch the offending program in the act.  You will then know what program to forbid, look for updates for, etc.  In the meantime, switching `/tmp` to tmpfs if you can will mitigate the boot-time issue.

Comment: We had considered switching /tmp/orbit-gdm to a tmpfs (not all of /tmp as we don't have the ram to spare)  however we decided against it due to concerns of a system crash if the space we allocated were to fill up.

Comment: There is a mount option when creating a tmpfs filesystem to specify the maximum size of the filesystem, size=.  Or you could use ramfs if you don't want the possibility of using swap.  Finally, if you think gdm is the problem you could always disable it, and launch X manually or when you login via command line.  You have to specify the desktop environment (/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc), then create a line in your .bash_profile to startx if it is not running.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc

Comment: We have a working fix for the symptoms (see temp fix listed in question under **update** ) that prevents it from running out of space and crashing, The question is what is causing this and how can we find the source not how to treat the symptoms.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem on RHEL6.8 with an 800 megabyte `/tmp/orbit-walker` directory (walker is my username).  This prevented my system from booting.

I found the problem by adding `init=/bin/bash` to my boot line to get a prompt, then doing

```
openvt -- /bin/bash
```

and then opening the virtual terminal with <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd>.  Searching around with `ps`, I found the `rm -rf /tmp/orbit-*` process that was hanging.

I was kill the hung `rm` and then continue the boot process with

```
exec /sbin/init
```

It is very difficult to delete the contents of a directory with a million files. Both 'find' and 'rm' insist on reading all the filenames and sorting them.  They both run for hours and then abort with 8G of core saying "too many files".

Here's something that works.

```
(cd /tmp/orbit-walker; /bin/ls -1 -f | xargs /bin/rm)
```

The -f option makes /bin/ls print without sorting and the -1 does it a line at a time.